# How do I get the day of the month in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to get the day of the month from a Date object but it seems that the `getDay()` method returns the day of the week. Is there a function that returns the day of the month?

Comment: `getDate()` - [you should check the MDN documentation for such things.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: I agree but isn't typing the question in google and getting the first result on stack overflow much easier.

Comment: @Nik, that's exactly what I did.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Use `date_object`[`.getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) to get the month day.

From the MDN docs link:

> *"Returns the day of the month for the specified date according to local time."*

Comment: I guess this question should not exist if they just named like getMonthDay() or something.

Comment: @AXSM yes, indeed. I just was confused with the function name and while searching thought its can't be correct answer and didn't try this function

Answer (score 51):

Try [getDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) instead. Confusing naming, but that's life...

Comment: life is life but such things could be named properly name of the function doesn't reflect real meaning

Answer (score 35):

```
var date = new Date().getDate();
```

From Mozilla Developer Network:

> Date.prototype.getDate()
> The getDate() method returns the day of the month for the specified date according to local time.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate

Answer (score 16):

```
const date = new Date();

const day = date.getDate();
const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
const year = date.getFullYear();
```

We have to increase the month by 1 because `getMonth()` returns from 0 to 11.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Buddy, add some comments, for example, why you are adding 1 to the month, or the range of numbers returned by `getDate`. That increases the chance of getting upvoted.

Comment: We add one day to the month because the months start from 0, like the indexes in an array. So January will be 0, Feb 1, March 2... etc.