# How to retrieve and set the last day of the month based on user input?

Tags: javascript

How to retrieve the last day of the month of user input in javascript?

I have a form with 2 datepickers. Currently, the form date is set as MM/YYYY (this is how I need it in the form) However, for date validation, I need the dates to be in format MM/DD/YYYY. The first date will just be set to MM/01/YYYY and the second date needs to be set as MM/lastDayOfMonth/YYYY. 
Below is what I have done so far. Which returns the last day of the month but along with timestamp and day.

```
var monthYear2 = $("#date2").val();
  var month = monthYear2.slice(0,2);
  var year = monthYear2.slice(3,7);
  var lastDay = new Date(year, month + 1, 0);
  var date2 = monthYear2.slice(0, 3) + lastDay + "/" + monthYear2.slice(3, 7)
```

I need my final variable of date2 to be in the format of MM/lastDayOfMonth/YYYY

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the day of the month in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845096/how-do-i-get-the-day-of-the-month-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you, but my form data is in format MM/YYYY. Can i still use getDate();?

Comment: `getDate` specfically grabs the day of the month from the object so you would use `lastDay.getDate()` to extract the numerical day from your lastDay object

Comment: Thank you, that definitely gives me the output I need but my validation is failing for some reason. But that's a different question. lol

Comment: Well except getDate(); when the month is February returns 30. Hmmm.

Comment: When `month` is `'02'`, `month + 1` is `'021'`, or October of the following year. (Or June, if your browser's really old.)

Comment: OK, so is there a method or something i could use to get the number of days in the month using my monthYear2 variable? which is equal to something like 04/2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get why you are creating a `Date` object with `month + 1`. Just use `month` if it is for the current month the user sent.

```js
const userInput = '02/2019',
  splitted = userInput.split('/'),
  month = splitted[0],
  year = splitted[1],
  
  firstDayDate = `${month}/01/${year}`,
  lastDayDate = `${month}/${new Date(year, month, 0).getDate()}/${year}`;
  
console.log(firstDayDate, lastDayDate);
```